# Changing to automatic clock causes output to go blank

Tags: verilog

Trying to automate the clock for Delay Flip Flop in the testbench, because I don't want always do it manually like this:

```
clock = 0
#5 clock = 1
#10 clock = 0
```

But suddenly, my code (below) doesn't work.

```
module d_flip_flop
(
    input [bit:0] a,
    input clock,
    output reg [bit:0] out
);
    parameter bit = 4 - 1;
    always @(posedge clock)
        begin
            out = a;
        end
endmodule
```

Testbench

```
module d_flip_flop_tb;
    reg [bit:0] a;
    reg clock;
    wire [bit:0] out;
    
    parameter bit = 4 - 1;

    d_flip_flop FLIP1
    (
        a,
        clock,
        out
    );

    initial
        begin
            clock = 0;
            forever
                begin
                    #5 clock = ~clock;
                end
            #1 assign a = 4'b0000;
            $display("INPUT  | %b", a);
            $monitor("OUTPUT | %b", out);
            #15 assign a = 4'b1111;
        end
endmodule
```

The output seems to be blank, so I don't know what to change while it's not outputting any error (using Icarus v10). Also when I tick-tock the clock manually, it was working alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the `forever` loop prevents the `$display` and `$monitor` code from executing.  You should separate the clock out into its own `initial` block.  I also added a `$finish` statement to cleanly terminate the simulation.

I had to move your `parameter` declarations above their usage because I got compile errors with your code on different simulators.

```
module d_flip_flop
#(    parameter bit = 4 - 1)
(
    input [bit:0] a,
    input clock,
    output reg [bit:0] out
);
    always @(posedge clock)
        begin
            out = a;
        end
endmodule

module d_flip_flop_tb;
    parameter bit = 4 - 1;
    reg [bit:0] a;
    reg clock;
    wire [bit:0] out;
    

    d_flip_flop FLIP1
    (
        a,
        clock,
        out
    );

    initial begin
            clock = 0;
            forever
                begin
                    #5 clock = ~clock;
                end
    end

    initial begin
            #1 a = 4'b0000;
            $display("INPUT  | %b", a);
            $monitor("OUTPUT | %b", out);
            #15 a = 4'b1111;
            #100 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

Now I see the output change:

```
INPUT  | 0000
OUTPUT | xxxx
OUTPUT | 0000
OUTPUT | 1111
```

---

Other notes:

You should not use `assign` inside an `initial` block.

`bit` is a reserved keyword for SystemVerilog.  Once `iverilog` supports that syntax, you might get compile errors.  You could change `bit` to something conventional like `WIDTH`.